# XSLT 2.0 using xsl copy/copy-of in for-each, overwriting certain attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm having troube copying nodes and overwriting elements in a for-each loop.

The code:

```
        <xsl:for-each select="key('doc_checks', @id, $doc_checks_File)">
            <xsl:if test="@id = $curID">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

Copies everything, which is fine, but I need to override two attributes (or rather, they should not be copied into the result document).

The document passed to the key function looks something like this:

```
<doc id="1eb79a4952644db089fd7eb049bb5b58" fileNameInDB="d041397121636931.xml" version="1">
        <docref id="ec699e0817fb46a0817b0fa276a249f8" fileNameInDB="d041385554715361.xml" href="ec699e0817fb46a0817b0fa276a249f8.xml" version="1">
            <docref id="91f233476f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070" fileNameInDB="d041385557506665.xml" href="91f233476f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.xml" navtitle="Model View Controller (MVC) Approach"version="1">
                <docref id="e1b625940c104b558e52f47afe5ddb4f" fileNameInDB="c511393250787627.xml" href="e1b625940c104b558e52f47afe5ddb4f.xml" version="1"/>
                </docref>
        </docref>
</doc>
```

I need that same structure in the output but without the fileNameInDB attribute.

**EDIT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet>

<xsl:key name="doc_checks" match="doc" use="@id"/>
<xsl:param name="doc_checks_File" select="fn:doc(fn:iri-to-uri('doc_checks.xml'))"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="docs">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="doc">

<xsl:variable name="curID" select="@id"/>

<xsl:for-each select="key('doc_checks', @id, $doc_checks_File)">
    <xsl:if test="@id = $curID">
        <!-- copy structure from $doc_checks_File -->
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>


</xsl:templates>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

INPUT:

```
<docs>
<doc id="1eb79a4952644db089fd7eb049bb5b58"/>
<doc id="2379a4952563db089fd7e2dz049bb648"/>
<!-- and so on -->
</docs>
```

referenced document doc_checks.xml (for key function):

```
<doc_checks>
    <doc id="1eb79a4952644db089fd7eb049bb5b58" fileNameInDB="d041397121636931.xml" version="1">
            <docref id="ec699e0817fb46a0817b0fa276a249f8" fileNameInDB="d041385554715361.xml" href="ec699e0817fb46a0817b0fa276a249f8.xml" version="1">
                <docref id="91f233476f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070" fileNameInDB="d041385557506665.xml" href="91f233476f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.xml" navtitle="Model View Controller (MVC) Approach"version="1">
                    <docref id="e1b625940c104b558e52f47afe5ddb4f" fileNameInDB="c511393250787627.xml" href="e1b625940c104b558e52f47afe5ddb4f.xml" version="1"/>
                    </docref>
            </docref>
    </doc>

<doc id="2379a4952563db089fd7e2dz049bb648">
<!-- a couple of docrefs, like above -->
</doc>
```

Expected output (the `<new>` is irrelevant)

```
<new>
<doc id="1eb79a4952644db089fd7eb049bb5b58">
<docref id="ec699e0817fb46a0817b0fa276a249f8" href="ec699e0817fb46a0817b0fa276a249f8.xml" version="1">
                <docref id="91f233476f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070" href="91f233476f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.xml" navtitle="Model View Controller (MVC) Approach"version="1">
                    <docref id="e1b625940c104b558e52f47afe5ddb4f"  href="e1b625940c104b558e52f47afe5ddb4f.xml" version="1"/>
                    </docref>
            </docref>
</doc>

<doc id="2379a4952563db089fd7e2dz049bb648">
<!-- the respective docref elements from doc_checks.xml -->
</doc>
</new>
```

Comment: Could you also post the expected output? --  And the key definition? -- And fix the example so the id  attribute is not empty?

Comment: okay, it should all be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
<xsl:template match="someElement">
    <xsl:for-each select="key('keyname', concat(@id, '+', @folder), $reuseFile)/child::*">
        <xsl:copy>
<!-- overwrite attribute -->
            <xsl:attribute name="rev" select="@ver"/>
<!-- exclude certain attributes -->
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*[fn:local-name() != 'somename']"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/> <!-- chooses the template below -->
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="abc | def">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="rev" select="@ver"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*[fn:local-name() != 'somename']"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

`xsl:copy-of` copies the selected node and its entire descendant tree, with no possibility to pick and choose. Try instead something like:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('doc_checks', @id, $doc_checks_File)[@id = $curID]"/>
```

and then have these two templates to handle the call:

```
<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@fileNameInDB"/>
```

**Caveat**: you did not post a reproducible example, so this may require some changes before it will work in your scenario.

---

### Edit:

In view of your added code, here's the suggested method in the context of a full stylesheet :

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="doc_checks" match="doc" use="@id"/>
<xsl:param name="doc_checks_File" select="document('doc_checks.xml')"/>

<xsl:template match="/docs">
    <new>
        <xsl:for-each select="doc">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('doc_checks', @id, $doc_checks_File)"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </new>
</xsl:template>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@fileNameInDB"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example (after correcting the `doc_checks.xml` document for well-formedness!!), the result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<new>
   <doc id="1eb79a4952644db089fd7eb049bb5b58" version="1">
      <docref id="ec699e0817fb46a0817b0fa276a249f8"
              href="ec699e0817fb46a0817b0fa276a249f8.xml"
              version="1">
         <docref id="91f233476f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070"
                 href="91f233476f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.xml"
                 navtitle="Model View Controller (MVC) Approach"
                 version="1">
            <docref id="e1b625940c104b558e52f47afe5ddb4f"
                    href="e1b625940c104b558e52f47afe5ddb4f.xml"
                    version="1"/>
         </docref>
      </docref>
   </doc>
   <doc id="2379a4952563db089fd7e2dz049bb648"><!-- a couple of docrefs, like above --></doc>
</new>
```

**Notes:**

1. Your first two templates are redundant; the *built-in template rules*
   already do that;
2. Your test `<xsl:if test="@id = $curID">` is redundant; the *key* already takes care of that.

Comment: I dont know if that's what I need. I'm not trying to copy anything from the document that the stylesheet processes but from a second document, which is accessed via the key function. See my edit.

Comment: I believe that **is** what you need - see the edit to my post.

Comment: Well, it's not 100% what I need... I have a template that matches the "doc" element in the input file but I also have other templates that match other elements in that file. The problem is that I dont really need to copy anything from the input file, I only need to copy things from the doc_checks.xml. Is it not possible in XSL to limit the copy to only the for-each loop?

Comment: "*The problem is that I dont really need to copy anything from the input file*' Why is that a problem - when nothing is in fact copied? --  "*I have a template that matches the "doc" element in the input file*" Why do you need such template - when you don't really need to copy anything from the input file? -- "*Well, it's not 100% what I need...*" I don't know what to do about that. I can only answer the question as asked.

Comment: I posted my solution: My code chooses some attributes while overwriting others and does the same for the child elements. I only needed to do this locally that's why your identity transform didnt work for me. I didnt need to copy anything from the document I was applying the stylesheet to but from another document. But I only needed to copy something from that document at a certain spot in the stylesheet.